# How to check whether "user" cancelled Helper SM Job Bless password dialog

Tags: swift, macos

Following is my JobBless code, I need help in finding out the error specifically when user cancels the Helper tool installation password dialog

```
    var authorization: AuthorizationRef?
    let status: OSStatus = AuthorizationCreate(nil, nil, [], &authorization)

    guard status == errAuthorizationSuccess else {
        return .failure(authFailed)
    }

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let blessStatus = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, label as CFString, authorization, &error)
    guard blessStatus else {

        //*** CHECK FOR CFERROR TO SEE WHETHER THE FAILURE IS DUE TO USER CANCELLING
        // THE PASSWORD REQUEST**
        print(error)

        return .failure(blessfailed)
    }
    return .success(())
```

I get the following error printed:

```
Error Domain=CFErrorDomainLaunchd Code=2
```

I expected kSMErrorLaunchDeniedByUser (11), but I received  kSMErrorInternalFailure(2). I am not sure whether I am looking into the right error enum. Please help.

```
(lldb) p kSMErrorLaunchDeniedByUser
(Int) $R0 = 11
(lldb) p kSMErrorInternalFailure
(Int) $R1 = 2
```

The reason I want this error number is to show an error screen if user cancels the dialog instead of entering the password. Please help

Comment: Does it work in the happy case? I suspect you have some other error in your whole setup.

Comment: Yes, it works well when I give proper password. It is an existing code, just I wanted to add a new error screen to show when the user cancels the password dialog

Comment: Hmmmm I'm not sure then. I've been using the [`Blessed`](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/Blessed) framework to wrap a bunch of these shitty APIs. The author has done a pretty thorough job of detecting all the various error conditions and reporting them in a more sensible way. Perhaps you can look into how he handles this case. As a last resort, you could try a [Technical Support Incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/)